# 389 Directory Server how to get the password status in java?

Tags: java, active-directory

I am using 389 Directory Server to store the passwords for user and I already set up some policies for the password. Now I am able to check the valid or invalid entries response. But now I want to get the status for the user password i.e. locked, expired etc. Is there any attribute or the same like windows active directory have controlAccesssPolicy. I am working on java. I found below useful information but not specific to 389 server.

[How to read LDAP password policy in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846134/how-to-read-ldap-password-policy-in-java)

[How do a LDAP search/authenticate against this LDAP in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172831/how-do-a-ldap-search-authenticate-against-this-ldap-in-java)

[LDAP: How to authenticate user with connection details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12163947/ldap-how-to-authenticate-user-with-connection-details)

Can anyone share information about this.
Thanks in advance.